# How to open a file in folders with discord.js

Tags: javascript, directory, discord.js

I am now coding a Discord bot in a folder named "bot", and I am making it play audio file. But I face a problem. If every files I want to make it play are stored in "bot", the folder will look mess. So I want to create a new folder named "music" in "bot". But I don't know to open the file in this way. Here is a part of my original code:

```
if (cmd === "play" && message.member.voice.channel) {
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        const dispatcher = connection.play('01. Snow halation.flac');
        dispatcher.on('start', () => {
            console.log('Now playing!');
        });
        dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
            console.log('Finished playing!');
            connection.disconnect();
        });
        dispatcher.on('error', console.error);
```

I want let file "01. Snow halation.flac" be in "music", and how can I make it play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const dispatcher = connection.play('./music/01. Snow halation.flac');
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)